# How are active states on Facebook determined?

Tags: facebook

If someone is "Active 5 minutes ago", "Active "3 minutes ago", or "Active 12 minutes ago", does that mean they're getting online and just ignoring messages? Is it an error? I know people text me during all hours of the night asking why I'm still awake because it states that I am active, when I in fact have closed out of messenger and am dead asleep.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't glitch. The moment you open up messenger or Facebook (I'm not sure about Facebook), it will change to active now. When you leave the app, it will say active 1m ago. Suppose you leave for an hour. It will say active 1h ago. if you come back on, it says active now. Usually it might be wrong by a hour sometimes (if you left 3h ago but it still says active 2h ago), but other then that it does not glitch.

Comment: The hour difference is due to rounding differences in your perception vs actuality